# The type 'List<int>' does not match the type 'string'

Tags: f#

In F#
`"Hello"+"World"` gives "`HelloWorld`". I mean the `+` operator can concatenate the strings.

```
Given this code:
let iprint list:List<int> =
 let stringList=int2String4List list         //convert the int list to string list
 List.foldBack (fun acc elem -> acc+elem+','  ) stringList  ""
```

but i faced with the error:

```
The type 'List<int>' does not match the type 'string'
```

It seems to me the F# interpreted the datatype of `stringList`  as int meanwhile it is a `List<string>`. but i do not know how does it happen?

```
List.foldBack : ('T -> 'State -> 'State) -> 'T list -> 'State -> 'State
```

This means, the datatype of first parameter of function and the list must be the same, but why it is insisting to accept `+` as an `int` operator, but not a string operator?

Comment: what is the signature of  `int2String4List` function?

Comment: let rec int2String4List (list:List<int>) :List<string>

Comment: Change signature of your function: `let iprint (list:List<int>) =`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed parenthesis in your function declaration, so the type annotation (`List<int>`) was applied to the function return value. This will compile:

```
let iprint (list:List<int>) =
    let stringList=int2String4List list
    List.foldBack (fun acc elem -> acc+elem+",") stringList  ""
```

By the way, isn't your `int2String4List` simply `List.map string`?

Also, the parameters of `fun acc elem -> ...` are in the wrong order. If you check the type of the function expected by `List.foldBack` you will see it's `'T -> 'State -> 'State` - the first parameter is an element of the list, the second one is the accumulator. There is not much difference in the sample you posted (both `'T` and `'State` are `string`), but there is a difference if you want to shorten it:

```
let iprint list =
    List.foldBack (fun elem acc -> (string elem) + "," + acc  ) list  ""
```

As @JoelMueller noticed in his comment, the shortest and fastest way to achieve this result is

```
let iprint =
    List.map string >> String.concat ","
```

Comment: Yes, `List.map string >> String.concat ","` is both shorter and performs better because it's not doing repeated naive string concatenation.